# a property of zero coupon bond in Brigo/Mercurio's "Interest Rate Models"

Tags: interest-rates, zero-coupon

Let $P(t,T)$ be the the value of a contract at time $t$. This contract guarantees its holder the payment of $1$ at time $T$.

consider $t<T<S$, when the interest rate is non-deterministic, do we have
$$\frac{P(t,S)}{P(T,S)}=P(t,T)$$
?

I think the answer is no, but Brigo gives it a proof when he calculate the forward rates(Page 11, paragraph after equation (1.18), the following is an image of page 11)

[image]

the main idea is:

consider $A:=1/P(T,S)$ as an amount of currency held at $S$, on the one hand, its value at $t$ is $P(t,S)/P(T,S)$; on the other hand, its value at $T$ is $1$, then discount it back to $t$, we get its value at $t$ is $P(t,T)$, hence 
$$\frac{P(t,S)}{P(T,S)}=P(t,T)$$

Would you mind telling me what's wrong with this proof?

Comment: Why does the amount $A:=1/P(T,S)$ held at $S$ has the value $P(t,S)/P(T,S)$ at $t$?

Comment: @Gordon by the def of $P(t,S)$: $1$ at $S$ equals $P(t,S)$ at $t$, hence $A$ at $S$ equals $P(t,S)A$ at $t$.

Comment: If $A$ is known at $t$, your argument is fine. Bu$1/P(T, S)$ is unknown at time $t$, for $t < T$.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding the valuation date/time to the bonds identifier will make it clearer. See below:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand "It is easy to see from the above:...". I think you simply replicate an FRA, right? so it should be $P(t;t,S)/P(t;t,T)=1+(S-T)P(t;T,S)$?

Comment: It is indeed replication, but it is replicating the forward bond. By definition, agreeing to buy the forward bond at P(t;T,S) means you pay this price, -P(t;T, S) at time T to get +1 at S, and the above strategy just replicates these flows. The final step is to use the usual arbitrage argument, and that is what ‘it is easy to see’ is alluding to,